# Best tools for running and compiling C on a Mac?

Tags: c

I have tried creating the file in vi (with auto indent on) and then compiling with "cc myFile.c" but I was wondering if there was something better but less complicated than eclipse.

Comment: I'm sure someone will suggest emacs. Eclipse is only complicated to set up though, not use. If you were on linux I'd suggest `KDevelop`. I'm fairly sure there's not a mac port though.

Comment: @Falmarri: of course there's a mac port of kdevelop.  It says so right on the front page of the kdevelop website.

Comment: Take a look at [Qt Creator](http://qt.nokia.com/products/developer-tools/).

Comment: @Stephen Canon: It says there's a windows version too but I'm pretty sure there's no binaries for anything other than linux. So you'd have to compile from source and I've done that and it's not easy.

Answer (score 6):

You can use XCode, but I assume you must have some objection to that or else you wouldn't be asking the question.

So, to help everyone answer your question: what don't you like about XCode?  What features do you want?  I wouldn't say the XCode editor is the best on the platform (though it's completely serviceable, offering autocomplete and coloring and indenting and all that usual stuff), but without knowing what you're looking for, I can't tell you what other editors you should look at.

Answer (score 0):

Might want to take a look at netbeans. Generally in the same space functionality wise as eclispse, but I find it does a much better job of staying out of the way when you don't need all the gizmos.

jEdit (Free, java), and Textmate (~$50, native) are good choices if you want a text editor that will syntax highlight, indent, etc.